# Export results of NET USER command from usernames in a TEXT file

Tags: windows, batch, cmd.exe

I have a text file with a list of usernames.
And for each username I would like to export the result of :

```
net user <username> /domain | findstr /R /C:"Account active"
```

in another text file where the results would be formatted like this :

```
userA - result of the command
userB - result of the command
userC - result of the command
...
```

I have this piece of code, but it does half of the things I want to do, as it displays in the command prompt only :

```
@echo off
for /F %%i in (users.txt) do (
    echo %%i
    net user %%i /domain | findstr /R /C:"Account active"
)
```

Could you please help me ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

**Prerquisites**

- You have an input text file populated with SAM account names:

```
user1
user2
user3
```

- The result will be in (Suppose user1 and user3 is active and user2 inactive):

```
user1 - Yes
user2 - No
user3 - Yes
```

Then (set `%InputFile%` to input file path and `%ResultPath%` to result file path) You can use this:

```
@Echo off & Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "InputFile=users.txt" & Set "ResultPath=result.txt"
For /f "Delims=" %%a in ('type "%InputFile%"') do (
  For /f "Tokens=3 Delims= " %%b in ('net user "%%a" /domain ^| find /i "Account active"') do set "active=%%~b"
  Echo %%~a - !active! >>"%ResultFile%"
)
```

Active Directory management and scripting is very flexible with Powershell:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
(Get-Content users.txt) | Foreach {
  If((Get-ADUser -Identity $_).Enabled){
    "$($_) - Yes" >>"result.txt"
  }Else{
    "$($_) - No" >>"result.txt"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Wasif

When I execute your script, here is the message I get :

`The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The user name could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221.

The system cannot find the path specified.
The user name could not be found.

More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2221.

The system cannot find the path specified.`

Comment: Have you read the whole answer properly? You need to replace the value of two variables. Have you done it?

Comment: I think I do :
`Set "InputFile=C:\temp\users.txt" & Set "ResultPath=C:\temp\result.txt"`
Where C:\temp is the folder that contains the files

But maybe I made something wrong here?

Comment: Are those text files in correct format?

Comment: Yes, but it works if I `rem` the `Set` line and replace variables with the path directly in the script !

Comment: Hello again ! I'm sorry, but I hadn't tested all the cases properly. When a username doesn't exist, DOS windows display the same error as above : "the user name could not be found" and in the result file these usernames are tagged YES. Maybe an `IF` would be useful to test either possibilities and then parse the result of the `NET` ?
Also, how can I make the result file to reset itself each time ?
Thank you =)